# Trend Smart Scan server updates thrash the disk

Tags: performance, anti-virus

Every 2 hours, Trend Worry Free business updates Smart Scan.

This process requires Trend to thrash through 6 gigabytes of data - this causes two issues

1. The file cache, full of LOB data, is lost and replaced with trend
   data.
2. The VSS based incremental backup system detects gigabytes of data
   change on the disk.

Given a low disk space condition, one will get the error "Smart scan pattern: Unable to update components. The update requires at least (6182)MB of space to complete"

One support article suggests some ini file options can be tweaked, to reduce the required data set to 3 gig.

Question is, what are others doing? Perhaps trend simply needs to be put on it's own member server?